# sort DataTable on one column independent of other columns

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I create a two column `DataTable` (id, name):

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DataColumn id = table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        id.AutoIncrement = true;
        id.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        id.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        id.ReadOnly = true;                  
        table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
```

The `DataColumn` named `id` is `AutoIncrementing` (e.g. identity).

Then I read a file, and add each line of the file as a row.

```
//for each line in file
table.Rows.Add(null,line);
```

Next, I sort the `DataTable` on the `DataColumn` named `name` using a `DataView`:

```
        DataView dv = table.DefaultView;           
        dv.Sort = "name";
        table = dv.ToTable();
```

Problem is, the `id` column gets sorted when I would prefer it not (basically I just want to sort the `name` column independently of the other column).

Only solution I could find was to have an intermediate step where I populate a `List<string>` with the file lines, then sort that, then populate the table.  Wondering if there was a more elegant (simple) solution?

Comment: Do you need the names only or the DataRows? If the latter, a name belongs to an ID.

Comment: Each `name` belongs to an `id`.  However, I only care about the id,name key,value pair _after_ name has been sorted.  E.g. the first alphanumerically sorted name should be 1, and the next 2, and so on.  I should also say I plan to insert this as a Table-Valued Parameter into SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
var orderedRows = table.AsEnumerable()
                       .OrderBy(r => r.Field<String>("name"));
```

or, if you just want the names:

```
var orderedNames = orderedRows.Select(r => r.Field<String>("name"));
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`.

**Edit**:

> Each name belongs to an id. However, I only care about the id,name
>   key,value pair after name has been sorted. E.g. the first
>   alphanumerically sorted name should be 1, and the next 2, and so on

Then you need to add the rows after you've sorted the lines:

```
var txtLines = File.ReadLines(path)
                   .OrderBy(l => l);

foreach(String  line in txtLines)
    tables.Rows.Add(null, line);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe you should just regenerate the id column if you are just worried about the values of id after the sort.

```
table.Columns["id"].ReadOnly = false;
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    table.Rows[i]["id"] = i + 1;
}
table.Columns["id"].ReadOnly = true;
```